# ReplyAll() function not working in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, outlook-addin

```
private void CreateEmailItem()
{
    Object selObject = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
    string sendernames = (selObject as Outlook._MailItem).SenderName;
    Outlook._MailItem eMail = (Outlook._MailItem)
    this.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    eMail = selObject as Outlook._MailItem;
    ((Outlook._MailItem)eMail).Body = "Approved";
    ((Outlook._MailItem)eMail).ReplyAll();
}
```

If we instead use ((Outlook._MailItem)eMail).Send(); its working, but while using ReplyAll() function its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to create a new mail item from scratch. Instead, you can use an item which is returned from the `ReplyAll` method. So, you can take the selected item in the Explorer window and cast it to a MailItem class.

```
Object selObject = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
Outlook._MailItem eMail = selObject as Outlook._MailItem;
Outlook._MailItem reply = eMail.ReplyAll();
```

After you can deal with the `reply` object and set its properties according to your needs.

You may find the [How To: Respond to an Outlook email programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/05/how-to-respond-to-an-email-programmatically/) article helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`ReplyAll` is a function that returns the newly created item. Your code above ignores the returned value and sets the `Body` property on the original item.

Comment: I want to do reply all as message body "APPROVED" to selected email, is there a way to do it? @Dmitry

Comment: yes, that tis what I am saying. ReplyAll returns the new message. Set the Body and other properties on that new returned message.

Comment: thanks D its working now but there is slight problem, its not creating a chain of email. Can we do that?

Comment: What "chain of email"?

Comment: It means that if i click on the approve button, "Approved" should come on the top of the previous mail or to mail which we are replying. In this case its only printing approve. So is there any way which can achieved our needs??? @Dmitry

Comment: Did you modify you code per my answer? What is your latest code? Do you call MailItem.Display to show the new item?